# multiple inheritance and variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Consider this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
protected:
    void foo(){ std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
};

class Bar
{
protected:
    void bar(){ std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; }
};

template<typename... Args>
class Test: public Args...
{
public:
    void test()
    {
            this->foo();
            this->bar();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Test<Foo, Bar> test;
    test.test();
    return 0;
}
```

As we can see compiler allows us to inherit from parameter pack. But when we could need this feature? How to use it properly?

**Update**

I want to see some use cases like [Nawaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415784/nawaz) has provided.
The only use case I see - policy based design, but would not be better if we enforce a list of needed policies like:

```
template<typename T, typename Policy1, typename Policy2, typename Policy3>
class SomeClass: public Policy1, public Policy2, public Policy3 { ... };
```

Comment: But you've answered yourself: `Test<Foo, Bar> test;`

Comment: Here is [one tiny example](https://github.com/snawaz/cson) that uses this feature.. and [this is the file](https://github.com/snawaz/cson/blob/master/include/cson/cson.h%2B%2B) which you can look at. And here is [a bigger, more complex example](https://github.com/snawaz/tagsql) that uses this feature extensively.

Answer (score 1):

One nice usage is compile time map. Refer to description [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/598107/Compile-Time-Map).

You may combine its usage with [policy based design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design) to achieve explosion of choices in class making.